# Iterating over a List of Maps (List<Map<Integer,String>>) and looking for specific values?

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of maps. `List<Map<Integer,String>> lines`.
I am looking to iterate over the list and all maps only looking at specific keys-values pairs trying to find a  matching string value - "hi".

Example: I'm only interested in looking at entry sets for specific keys range 5-10 and checking the values for a match. Below is what I was planning. A method to iterate over list check each map for any matches.

Is there a better or more cleaner/efficient approach for this?

```
//basic logic
for(Map<Integer,String> map : lines)
{
   return map.entrySet().stream()
     .filter(e -> 11 > e.getKey().intValue() && e.getKey().intValue() >= 5)
     .anyMatch(entry -> entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("hi"));
}
```

Comment: **I am looking to iterate over the list and all maps only looking at specific keys-values pairs trying to find a matching string value** Then what does it do? **I'm only interested in looking at entry sets for specific keys range 5-10 and checking the values for a match** That's different from what you just described. In general for this type of question you should really give an example input and output set, and explain the purpose of the invariants in the problem.

Comment: Seems like you need an interval map. You can try to use [Guava RangeMap](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#rangemap)

Comment: @tony what is your method supposed to return?

Comment: @flakes. Yes so I am basically wanting to look through all the maps in list, if a match is found in this case for "hi" then will return true. No need to continue looking. Just looking if the matching string is present at all.

Comment: @Misha. Just returning true or false. Did not include entire method just the logic that will be used to check. But basically true/false if the matching string is found at all in entire list.

Comment: @flakes. And Additionally I was only interested in a range of entries in each map, so no need to check each single entry's value just the ones that fall in between that range [5-10]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already using streams, you could also stream the list:

```
return lines.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(entry -> 11 > entry.getKey() && entry.getKey() >= 5)
            .anyMatch(entry -> entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("hi"));
```

This will return `true` if any Map in the List has an Entry with a key between 5 and 10 (inclusive) and a value of "hi" (ignoring case), and will return `false` otherwise. This is my best guess at your original intent; if I am incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't they `collect` in the end? This returns a boolean.

Comment: It looked like the OP wanted to return a boolean, since their stream statement started with `return`, though their loop always terminates in the first iteration.

Comment: Since OP is only interested in keys in the range 5-11, you could suggest an IntStream. Probably more performant than looping over all keys and testing whether they're in range.

Comment: @mypetlion do you mean streaming over [5, 11) and then doing map lookups based on the current element?

Comment: That is what I meant, yes. Though now I'm wondering whether the average compiler would be capable of optimizing that sort of thing for you.

Comment: How do you recommend pulling each map out of the list, in that case? I can't say I am a savant with streams.

Comment: @BenP. Something like this should do it (sorry for unreadable comment...): `lines.stream().anyMatch(map -> IntStream.range(5, 11).mapToObj(map::get).filter(Objects::nonNull).anyMatch(entry -> entry.equalsIgnoreCase("hi")));`

Comment: @mypetlion They probably wouldn't be capable of optimising that...  but it may well also not be an optimisation depending on how many entries the `Map`s have that _aren't_ in that range.

Comment: @user2478398 or shorter, `lines.stream().anyMatch(map -> IntStream.range(5, 11).mapToObj(map::get).anyMatch("hi"::equalsIgnoreCase));`. This utilizes the fact that `equalsIgnoreCase` does already handle `null` arguments (returning `false`). Alternatively, you can also use `lines.stream().anyMatch(map -> IntStream.range(5, 11).anyMatch(i -> "hi".equalsIgnoreCase(map.get(i)));`

Comment: To those, who don’t like nested `anyMatch`s, the idiomatic solution would be `lines.stream() .flatMap(map -> IntStream.range(5, 11).mapToObj(map::get)) .anyMatch("hi"::equalsIgnoreCase)`

Comment: so method is simply to check if the matching string exists in the list of maps. If it is found will just return true or else false if not present.  But it we are only interested in looking at a certain range of entries for each map.

Comment: @Holger Yep, thought there'd be a way to do it with `flatMap`.  It was 2AM here and I didn't have an IDE open to test anything when I wrote that last night :).  Latter one's much better than my approach for anyone viewing these comments later.

Answer (score 2):

If the maps are rather large I would go with [user2478398](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864869/iterating-over-a-list-of-maps-listmapinteger-string-and-looking-for-specif#comment92644860_52864923)'s comment. If it is possible, use `SortedMap` or `NavigableMap` and you can easily apply `NavigableMap#subMap`. Then the `Stream` would look like this:

```
lines.stream()
     .flatMap(m -> m.subMap(5, 11).values().stream())
     .anyMatch("hi"::equalsIgnoreCase);
```